# Manufacturer wanted: Raspberry Pi case without SD card slot / protected SD card slot

Tags: sd-card, security, case

Is there any Raspberry Pi enclosure (beside self-made cases) that does *not* provide access to the SD card from outside or does cover the SD card so that the card cannot be directly accesed?

**Background:** I'd like to use the Pi for security relevant applications and want to prohibit direct access to the card. (I would add sealing paint/glue/tape to the enclosure parts to be able to recognize if the case has been opened.)

It's not required that the case has special mounting components (i.e. for industrial use). However, if it has such mounting components it would be OK anyway.

Manufacturers and/or resellers of such a case in Europe or even Germany are desired.

Answer (score 3):

have you considered [low profile micro sd adapter](https://www.adafruit.com/products/966)? it definitely hides sd card and you may use any case available on the market, just cover the hole with something:

[image: low profile micro sd adapter]

Comment: Hmm, nice solution. But, it seems the adapter exceeds the PCB bound by 1-2 mm. I have a standard case here having a 1-2mm gap between the case and the PCB, so covering the slot from inside seems to be impossible. +1 anyway.

Comment: [This](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/low-profile-micro-sd-card-adapter-for-raspberry-pi-macbook.html) adapter sits flush with the Pi board so should let you block the holes from the inside.